# HTML Element "OffsetLeft" is not correct when I refresh my page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make a navbar, with a slider indicator on the bottom of links.
I'm using Nav and NavLink from react-router-dom to display my links in the navbar.

Here is the code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import I18nWrapper from '../i18n-wrapper';

const usePathname = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return location.pathname;
};

const MenuLinks = () => {
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const indicatorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    // I move slider and setActiveIndex when I change the page
    if (pathName === '/a') {
      setActiveIndex(0);
      moveSlider(0);
    }
    if (pathName === '/b') {
      setActiveIndex(1);
      moveSlider(1);
    }
    if (pathName === '/c') {
      setActiveIndex(2);
      moveSlider(2);
    }
  }, [activeIndex, pathName, indicatorRef]);
  const moveSlider = (index: number) => {
    const indicator = indicatorRef.current;
    if (indicator) {
      const tab = indicator.parentElement?.children[index] as HTMLElement;
      // When I log here, the "tab.offsetLeft" is not the same as if I log "indicator.parentElement?.children" and check the offsetLeft in the children
      indicator.style.width = `${tab.offsetWidth}px`;
      indicator.style.transform = `translateX(${tab.offsetLeft - 218}px)`;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Nav className="me-auto ms-4">
      <NavLink to="/a" activeClassName="active-page">
        <I18nWrapper translateKey="a" />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/b" activeClassName="active-page">
        <I18nWrapper translateKey="b" />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/c" activeClassName="active-page">
        <I18nWrapper translateKey="c" />
      </NavLink>
      <div className="menu-border-bottom" ref={indicatorRef}></div>
    </Nav>
  );
};
export default MenuLinks;
```

so as I said in the commented code : When I log here (moveSlider function), the "tab.offsetLeft" is not the same as if I log "indicator.parentElement?.children" and check the offsetLeft in the children

tab.offsetLeft (371) : [image: tab.offsetLeft console log]
indicator.parentElement?.children (517) (checking the corresponding index of course) : [image: indicator.parentElement?.children console log]

The UI result of this issue is that the slider indicator goes on bottom of the wrong tab and its width is not perfect.
But once my page is loaded, if I switch tab this work perfectly.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you provide a working codeSandbox or other link that demonstrates the issue?  The code above is not sufficient to actually run (eg, doesn't include your CSS, or the `I18nWrapper`, which could both be important here), and I don't know that too many people will be able to confidently identify the problem based on source code alone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a sandbox so can't answer you question.

But I recommand implement this feature with Framer Motion. it's is awesome, and easy to use. your feature can be done with single `<div layoutId="indicator" />`